# Обновить Ruby 2.3.0 до версии 2.4.2 Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ruby, update

Столкнулся с необходимость обновить версию Ruby, нашел несколько вариантов, большинство с которых сводятся к использовании команды

```
sudo apt-get install ruby2.4.2 ruby-switch
```

Но когда я выполняю данную команду вот что мне возвращает терминал

```
Чтение информации о состоянии… Готово
E: Не удалось найти пакет ruby2.4.2
E: Не удалось найти пакет по регулярному выражению «ruby2.4.2»
```

Пробовал писать через пробел `ruby 2.4.2` при этом отображается что уже установлена самая новая версия ruby и вот такой результат

```
обновлено 0, установлено 0 новых пакетов, 
для удаления отмечено 0 пакетов, и 323 пакетов не обновлено.
```

Чувствую что явно что-то не так делаю, но не могу понять что - подскажите, пожалуйста

rvm не использую, использую rbenv

Comment: недавно делал , но забыл как, в закладках с гитхаба:ubuntu_rvm, rvm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В репах ubuntu `16.04` нет свежее `2.3.0` и вряд ли будет. Тут или смириться или пойти в [официальную](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/) документацию и ставить в систему всякие [ruby-build](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#ruby-build)\[ruby-install](https://github.com/postmodern/ruby-install) с [rvm](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/documentation/installation/#rvm).

Comment: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv